# Regex to replace variables in configuration file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have got three types of variables in my config file which are used by bash scripts in different functions

```
PACKAGES=(base linux sudo neovim)
HOOKS=()
VOLUMES=()
UEFI="yes"
BOOTLOADER="efistub"
PATH="/dev/mapper/luks"
```

I have one function which is updating them by interacting with user or directly from config file

```
set_option() {# with two args
    if [[ "$1" =~ "PACKAGES" ]]; then
        sed -i "/PACKAGES=/s/\)/\ $2\)/" "$CONFIG_FILE"
    elif grep -Eq "^$1.*" "$CONFIG_FILE"; then
        sed -i -E "/$1=/s/REGEX/\"$2\"/" "$CONFIG_FILE"
    else 
        sed -i -E "s/$1=REGEX/$1=$2/" "$CONFIG_FILE"
    fi
}
```

`set_option` is working fine for `PACKAGES` it is adding new packages to the list like

```
set_option "PACKAGES" "git"
```

**I am struggling with**

1. `set_option` to update variable like `HOOKS` or `VOLUMES` and replace anything inside or empty `()` with new values i.e. `(lvm2 filesystems)` or `(@ @home @tmp)` respectively.
2. `set_option` to update variable like `UEFI` or `PATH` which have quoted strings with new values in quotations i.e. `no` or `/dev/mapper/crypt`

Comment: Using `sed` to manipulate nontrivial shell script code is inherently brittle. Probably a better solution would be to use a simpler configuration format, and perhaps then generate the format you try to use as input from that simpler format instead if you need to be able to `source` it from other shell scripts.

Comment: yes certainly sed is not that right for job. But i am open to any other option as well. Changing format is not an option.